# MongoDb aggregation - check if values in array are present in collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I'm pretty new to MongoDb. I have a collection of some products, some of them contains an array of ids of other products in the same collection:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "relatedProducts": [
      "1", "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "relatedProducts": [
      "4", "5"
    ]
  }
]
```

Problem is, not all of the products that are in that relatedProducts array are available in that collection.
I have to create an aggregation that will modify those arrays so only id of available products are present in it. So, for example, if product of id = 5 is not present in that collection, relatedProducts of object with id 2 above will have only one entry in the array ("4").

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first fetch all the product `_id`'s, then update the documents accordingly.

Here's how I would do this:

```
const ids = await db.collection.distinct('id');
await db.collection.updateMany(
    {
        relatedProducts: {$nin: ids}
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                relatedProducts: {
                    $setIntersection: [{$ifNull: ["$relatedProducts", []]}, ids]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```